# HEROKU Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/app/distpublic/index.html'

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, heroku

I know there are alot of questions like this on the site but I ihave tried everything i could on this site, the best I could get to work on heroku is to display a text on the browser, I have been struggling with this code for 2 days now, no success, below is my directory layout.
[image of my directory structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mSCii.png)

so below are my code

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/public/"));

app.get("/", (req, res, next) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + "public", 'index.html'));
   
    //res.send('Testing one two');
});

const port = process.env.PORT || '5000';
app.listen(port, () => console.log("Server running on port 5000"));
```

when I run this code on my machine it works well, in fact there are close to 5 ways and could change the code and it still works on my machine, but not on heroku, the best I have gotten horoku to work is just to display a text. i need on how to make this work, it been more than 2days now, I don't even understand the directory not found in the error msg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a solution which will work for you, but you have to restructure your project first.

- first move the server.ts into the root directory.
- secondly move the public folder that contains your static file into
  the root directory also and delete the src folder.

Below are the solutions.

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/public"));

app.get("/", (req, res, next) => {
    res.sendFile( path.resolve( __dirname, 'public/index.html' ) );
});

const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;
app.listen(port, () => console.log("Server running on port 5000"));
```

also your port number is a string, that might become a problem later.